# swagger-codegen-cli: java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config

Tags: swagger, code-generation, openapi

I'm trying to execute this command in the command prompt, to generate code for python:

```
java -jar modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
  generate \
  -i http://localhost/test/swagger-docs/api-docs.json \
  -l python -o c:\temp\python_testapi_client
```

And it shows me this error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:89)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:223)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
```

And when I open this file in my browser, it contains:

```
{
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "apis": [{
    "path": "\/v1-machinetags",
    "description": "Deletes machine tags by they titles."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos",
    "description": "Uploads photo with tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-bymachinetags",
    "description": "List of photos with possibility filtering by Machine tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-bytags",
    "description": "List of photos with possibility filtering by tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-user-bymachinetags",
    "description": "List of photos of a specific user with possibility filtering by machine tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-user-bytags",
    "description": "List of photos of a specific user with possibility filtering by tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos",
    "description": "Deletes photo."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-machinetags",
    "description": "Associate photo with machine tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-photos-tags",
    "description": "Associate photo with tags."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-resources",
    "description": "Add a new RDF resource ."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-tags",
    "description": "Deletes tags by they titles."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-triplets",
    "description": "Get All triplets."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-triplets-bylanguages",
    "description": "Get Resources by a given language."
  }, {
    "path": "\/v1-triplets-bytypes",
    "description": "Get Resources by a given type."
  }],
  "apiVersion": "0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Symfony2",
    "description": "My awesome Symfony2 app!",
    "TermsOfServiceUrl": null,
    "contact": null,
    "license": null,
    "licenseUrl": null
  },
  "authorizations": []
}
```

Comment: The swagger definition doesn't look right--do you really have escape characters in the paths?  Perhaps you can post the definition in a gist to avoid formatting issues.  It seems like it can't read the swagger definitinon at all.

Comment: Okay; do you have any idea for generating swagger specification using Symfony..I found swagger-ui-bundle but it does not allow it, I tried also with nelmio and its integration of swagger but the result is as you see

Comment: Did you find the solution to resolve this issue? @Nada

Comment: I am facing the same issue when trying to generate server via command line. I tried the same with the online editor it successfully generated, ASP.Net Core server and Spring but failing silently for nodejs-server and python-flask